# Postgresql: in user-defined types what is the send function used for?

Tags: postgresql

I came across the send_function and receive_function for user-defined types in Postgresql (see [Manual entry on CREATE TYPE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtype.html)). It says there that both functions are used to participate in binary input/output. I don't really understand what is meant by that? How can I use binary input and output? Is that the case when I access the database via a ODBC/JDBC driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binary input and output is supported for binary `COPY` and, yes, for binary transfer in the PostgreSQL wire protocol.

In many situations binary transfer actually performs worse than text transfer. It is only recommended for very select situations. Unless you have a very specific problem to solve, you do not need binary transfers.

PgJDBC supports the binary PostgreSQL protocol. I don't know if the ODBC driver does. You shouldn't generally use it anyway.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the answer! So even when inserting in a bytea data field it uses the textual input and not the binary, if I understood correctly? SO it doesn't depend on the data type of the underlying field but really on the protocol used?

Comment: @navititious Correct. Any given data type can have both binary and textual inputs and outputs. The textual input and output functions are required; the binary ones are optional. `bytea` is usually exchanged in textual format using a hexadecimal encoding (Pg 9.1 and above) or octet escape notation (Pg 9.0 and below), rather than binary on the wire. `bytea` is one of the few cases where transferring the data in binary form can be more efficient and worth the hassle. The PostgreSQL protocol lets you transfer some columns in textual form and some in binary. Anyway, most likely you don't need this.

Comment: @navititious If you're really curious about the inner workings I suggest you use wireshark to examine the protocol exchanges, or enable some of the low level debug settings in PostgreSQL and the client driver (JDBC/ODBC/etc) you're using, so you can see how the client converses with the server.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clarified all my questions :-)

Comment: A good use case for using binary over text would be in projects like PGVector. Inserting `Vector` via SQL text in Python is too slow. Instead, you could use bytea and avoid serialization cost in client. https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector/blob/6d88a9e1d2c304223ae783258f5a509a4a9f4737/src/vector.c#L388